# Customizing JSON output in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP 2.4, what is the correct syntax to `foreach` through my data in order to customize the contents and structure of JSON output from my controller?

I currently have the following method, which creates a .json that directly mirrors Cake's internal array of all my posts:

```
public function points() {
$this->autoRender = false; // We don't render a view in this example
$this->Post->recursive = -1; //Don't return stuff we don't need

return json_encode($this->Post->find('all'));
}
```

This creates JSON that looks like this, with each post's data the child of its own Post object (prettified with carriage returns so you can read it):

```
[{"Post":{"id":"1",
          "user_id":"1",
          "organism_id":"0",
          "title":"Title Text",
          "lat":"44.54401744186992",
          "lng":"-68.26070404052734",
          "body":"Body Text",
          "created":"2014-01-19 07:13:29",
          "modified":"2014-01-19 07:13:29"}
 },
 {"Post":{"id":"2",
          "user_id":"1",
          "organism_id":"0",
          "title":"Title Text",
          "lat":"44.54401744186992",
          "lng":"-68.26070404052734",
          "body":"Body Text",
          "created":"2014-01-19 07:13:29",
          "modified":"2014-01-19 07:13:29"}
 }]
```

This is a problem, because (A) For performance reasons, I might not want to dump all the data for each post into the JSON, and (B) for output to Google Maps, I need to output each post's data as child objects of one Posts object, like so:

```
{"Posts":[
    {"id":"1",
    "user_id":"1",
    "organism_id":"0",
    "title":"Title Text",
    "lat":"44.54401744186992",
    "lng":"-68.26070404052734",
    "body":"Body Text",
    "created":"2014-01-19 07:13:29",
    "modified":"2014-01-19 07:13:29"
},
    {"id":"2",
    "user_id":"1",
    "organism_id":"0",
    "title":"Title Text",
    "lat":"44.54401744186992",
    "lng":"-68.26070404052734",
    "body":"Body Text",
    "created":"2014-01-19 07:13:29",
    "modified":"2014-01-19 07:13:29"}]}
```

I know I somehow need to `foreach` through the data and build an array. How does this work?  `foreach ($posts as $post):` doesn't work inside the controller.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) - it explains why you should request this via .json extension. and not just like any normal http request. Then foreach() your data and create a final array you can set() to the view for serialization.

Comment: Thanks Mark- I read that first before posting. When I go into production I'll use `$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');`, but first I need to read my JSON to figure out why my Javascript doesn't like it!

Comment: How do I foreach the data in the controller? I know how to do it in a view but CakePHP doesn't seem to like the same syntax:

 `foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $marker = array(
   'id' => $post['Post']['id'],
   'lat' => $post['Post']['lat'],
   'lng' => $post['Post']['lng'],
   'title' => $post['Post']['title'],
   'body' = $post['Post']['body']);
  $markers[] = $marker;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

In the controller:

```
public function points() {
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax'); //Don't respond to non-AJAX requests
    $this->Post->recursive = -1; //don't return info from other controllers
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}
```

In /view/posts/json/points.ctp:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
$markers[] = array(
    'id' => $post['Post']['id'],
    'lat' => $post['Post']['lat'],
    'lng' => $post['Post']['lng']
    ); //make an array of the contents of each post I want to include

}

$data = array(
'Posts' => $markers); //Make everything the child of a 'Posts' object

 echo json_encode($data); //Turn it into JSON!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```
$data = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
      $data[] = $post['Posts'];
}

$postdata['Posts'] = $data;

 echo json_encode($postdata);
```

Comment: I tried almost exactly that and Cake threw a wall of errors, including 'undefined index' and 'maximum depth reached'- your code did the same thing.

Thank you though, because your code let me know I can use `$markers[] = array(` inside a `foreach` loop, instead of making a new `marker` array and adding it to `markers` each time!  That should cut down on my overhead a bit.

Comment: Can you please paste the array return from the query, may I help you more.

Comment: `Notice (8): Undefined index: Posts [APP/View/Posts/json/points.ctp, line 5]`, repeated 65x, once for each item in the controller, then  `$data = array(
 (int) 0 =&gt; null,
 (int) 1 =&gt; null,
 (int) 2 =&gt; null,
 (int) 3 =&gt; null,`, up to 64, then a stack trace.

I have a solution that works just fine, though- check the other answer.

Comment: can you please paste the code in view file?
If possible paste the array print too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Hash` Utility:

```
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all');
    $posts = array('Posts' => Hash::extract($posts, '{n}.Post'));
    $this->set('posts', posts);
```